# Issue with mapping in Scala using Cassandra DB

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I am trying to connect several Cassandra tables and display them using Scala.
I am getting the error:

```
 error: value map is not a member of model.UserMap
       mapResult.map(x => x.map(xx => xx.map(xxx =>
```

Here is my code:

```
import database.UserConnProvider
import database.PhantomUserRepository
import database.PhantomUserMapRepository
import com.softwaremill.macwire._
lazy val cassConn = wire[UserConnProvider]
val user = cassConn

import com.outworkers.phantom.connectors.CassandraConnection
import com.datastax.driver.core._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
val connection = user.get()
implicit val session: Session = connection.session
implicit val keySpace = connection.provider.space //provider.space
val config: com.typesafe.config.Config = ConfigFactory.load()
val tableName: String = "map"

import controllers.UserController
import com.outworkers.phantom.connectors.CassandraConnection
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

lazy val phantomUserMapRepo = new PhantomUserMapRepository(cassConn.get() , ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)
val userMapRepo = phantomUserMapRepo

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import play.api.libs.json._


val mapResult = userMapRepo.findMap("tc")
mapResult.map(x => x.map(xx => xx.map(xxx =>
  for(iter <- xxx.ticker.toArray) {
    println(iter)
  }
)))
```

Database definitions:

- Keyspace: `users`
- Tables: `user_info`, `map`, `tc_codes_map`.
- `user_info` connects to `map` through `company_code`.
- `map` has `ticker` column which connects to `tc_codes_map`

Would appreciate any tips!

Thank you!

Comment: can you post source for `findMap` function, or better for `PhantomUserMapRepository`

Comment: Your problem is Scala specific here. `userMapRepo.findMap("tc")` returns a `UserMap`, which probably means you're using `Await` on the future returned by phantom, which is actively discouraged. Paste the code for that and we can help further.